# Web-App using Hibernate that queries a SQL Server 2005 encrypted column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sql-server-2005, encryption

we are devolping a web-application using Spring 3.1.2 and Hibernate 4.1.7 with a database SQL Server 2005.

On a table we've got a column encrypted and we need to perform some queries like, for example, this one:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY PasswordFieldSymmetricKey
DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'myPassword'

SELECT id, 
       plain,
       cipher, 
       CONVERT(varchar(50),
       DecryptByKey(cipher)) AS 'Decrypted'
FROM TS_OWN.cryptest;

GO
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY PasswordFieldSymmetricKey
```

As a solution, [someone](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/0a20aa81-5ec1-484a-ab03-73c4a0e282fa/) proposed to create a view that manages the decryption but we need that no one must see the decrypted data, and of course DBA for example could query that view.

At the same time we don't want to perform the decryption on java side, due to some heavy aggregation logic that is expected to be performed by database engine due to performance reasons.

A possible solution is to create a view that performs decryption, aggregations and then encrypts the result one more time, performing decryption of the aggregated values on Java side.

Does someone know alternatives?

Thank you all,
*Luca*

Comment: Have you tied native sql qury session.createSQLQuery("your query").list();

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong and surely not skilled on SQL Server, but `OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY` seems to be something like a command/directive not part of the query. In addition we would like not to handle arrays of object and we would like to know if does a more elegant solution exists to handle this kind of crypted cols, maybe through hibernate.

Comment: @Dolfiz Have you ever found an elegant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a server-side perspective, the most transperent solution is to use [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate.html). This library comes with several Hibernate UserTypes for encrypting text/password fields.

As mentioned in the reference documentation, there are limitations:

> But encryption sets a limitation on your Hibernate usage: security
>   standards establish that two different encryption operations on the
>   same data should not return the same value (due to the use of a random
>   salt). Because of this, none of the fields that are set to be
>   encrypted when persisted can be a part of a WHERE clause in your
>   search queries for the entity they belong to.

While your HQL/SQL queries will hide the decrypting complexity, you won't get the same performance as with a specific database decryption function.

Using database decryption functions performs better, but then all your queries will be embedded in views and that's going to change dramatically the way you use Hibernate.

You could map [entities to views](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/HistoryTriggersAndHibernate) instead, but you'll have to pay attention to DML statements (some DBs offer [updatable views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx), others give you materialized views or  you might use INSTEAD OF triggers).

One possible solution for OPEN/CLOSE SYMETRIC is to use your own @Decrypt annotation and add an aspect to insert those right after the transaction starts and right before it ends. This will work because the sql session/connection is bound to the current transaction/thread.

Comment: I've been looking for a hibernate solution using SqlDialect, what do you think about that? Adding arbitrary sql before a query, sth like `open symmetric key blahblah` and  map the column to a formula. But I couldn't find a way to add arbitrary sql to the generated sql.

Comment: The SqlDialect doesn't provide you hooks for intercepting query statements, and you want that on a transaction level scope. Check my updated answer.